# How to remove deatils from faultString in WebSphere

Tags: web-services, security, websphere

I have a web service running on WebSphere.  When an invalid request is sent to the WS, I get a response with a soapenv:Fault object that includes a "faultstring" that contains a full stack trace.  This is undesirable in a production environment, as it contains lots of program details, paths, class names, etc.  How can I disable this from being returned to the client?

Comment: So maybe catch a fault on the client side and throw your business exception instead with less data in it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Gas, but I'm responsible for the web service on the server-side.  I'm exposing this web service, not consuming it.

Comment: Maybe add example of your service method and that full stack trace that you would like to hide. It will be easier to understand what you want to avoid. How about putting your business logic in try/catch and sending your custom fault. But fault info should give the client enough knowledge to learn what was the reason of the fault, so he can fix his code.